# How to disable task scanning for PHP edition of Netbeans 7

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-6.9, netbeans-plugins, netbeans-7

In NetBeans 6.9  I use [**this**](http://wiki.netbeans.org/ScanOnDemand) , but how to do it in NetBeans 7 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that as long as you have the Tasks window closed (not minimized), it doesn't scan. At least it doesn't seem to scan for me on 7.0 (and don't think it did before w/ 6.9 either).

Another option that I saw in the help is that you can select only to scan the currently editing file. That might boost performance if you still want the feature on but just without all the slow scanning.

Finally, maybe try removing all the ToDo Patterns in Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove all task patterns. It's one has to left at list. But try to export settings, unzip it, then find:

\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\tasklist\todo.properties

and write this:

```
patterns=
scanCommentsOnly=true
```

then zip it back and import no the netbeans. Fortunately task pattern list is empty now!